# Incrementing a value in an InnoDB table using MySQL REPLACE

Tags: mysql, replace

I would like to know if it is possible to use `REPLACE` MySQL statement in an InnoDB table to see if the key in the table already exists, if it does then increment the value by certain number (for instance 50), else insert a new record with with a certain value (50). Something like this:

```
 REPLACE INTO test(id, NumValue) VALUES (1, NumValue + 50)
```

This statement doesn't work. It inserts/updates to `NULL` value. If there is a way to do this using `REPLACE` statement what is the correct syntax? I know I could do it in couple steps, first using `SELECT` statement to find out if the record already exists, if it does then do an `UPDATE`, if it doesn't, then do an `INSERT`. But I was hoping it could be achieved by using just one step, using `REPLACE`. And also, I want to avoid using sub-queries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: it's not duplicate. I am not asking about REPLACE function. I want to use REPLACE to increment existing value if it exists, or insert new if it does not. That question only talks about inserting/updating, not incrementing

Comment: Man but you even look at those links... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html look here - it's first example.

Comment: Yep, that answers my question. Still don't think this is a duplicate though.

Comment: Of course it is. Even subject of this topic is insert or **update if exists**.

Comment: I just read the description, it actually might not work on InnoDb table